Assigning my custom class to an object/widget from a .ui file
Writing my 1st code in python, how can I create an instance of a class of my own and assign it to an object/widget from a .ui file?
Something like this:
import sys
from PyQt6.uic import loadUi
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTableWidget

class MyTable(QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, name: str):
        super().__init__()
        self.name = name

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        loadUi("table.ui", self)

        self.my_table: MyTable = MyTable("History Class")
        print(self.my_table.name)  # >> History Class
        self.my_table: MyTable = self.findChild(QTableWidget, "table")
        self.my_table.__class__ = MyTable  # ???
        print(self.my_table.name)  # >> AttributeError: 'MyTable' object has no attribute 'name'

        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainWindow()
    app.exec()
    sys.exit()

(my table.ui is just a QtWidgetTable with several rows and colums created in Qt Designer)

Is your "table.ui" really just a QTableWidget or is it a widget that contains a QTableWidget

You cannot "change" the class of an instance and overwriting its name certainly wouldn't do that, as much as dressing as a fish doesn't make you a fish. What are you trying to achieve with the above attempt?

@Wombatz, It is inside a QWidget

@musicamante, I want to a have QTableWidget with some of my own properties and methods. I know how to inherit classes, but how do u inherit an object defined in an .ui file?

@eli Then use widget promotion. MyTable should be set as the promoted class name in the UI for table. Do some research about widget promotion as there are plenty of examples. Once you do that, self.table will be automatically created as the instance of your MyTable subclass. The only difference is that you cannot add custom arguments in the constructor, but you can add dynamic properties in Designer and access them with self.property() (or even by adding a custom property with the @pyqtProperty decorator and a relative property setter).

@musicamante, Thanks. I did try to do promotion with QtDesigner, but with no success. I'll try again.

@eli If you did try it and it didn't work, please edit your post with a proper [mre] of it, including the script with the subclass definition (in case you use another file) and the UI file that uses it.
